# How can I get paramMap of ActivatedRoute inside ngxs state

Tags: angular, routes, state, ngxs

I need to update my ngxs state depending on different navigation routs, but when I use

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

in the constructor in the state and try to use it inside the action I get empty params.

I can pass the route as a payload when dispatching a function, but I doubt if it's a good idea to dispatch the same function inside ngOninit of every routing component.

I installed ngxs/router-plugin, but have no idea how to get the route from it. I was searching on youtube tutorials and modest documentation with no result.

Please help

Comment: I call the action from a service and I need to know what is the URL when the action is called

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it answers your questions! @MrOwl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's understand your questions

1. Should inject the router into Ngrx store

You should not inject the router into the store. Only mutate the store by dispatching the actions. Use payload to send the data with actions.

2. I doubt if it's a good idea to dispatch the same function inside ngOninit of every routing component

There is nothing wrong in dispatching the same actions into multiple components but for your case using the route resolver would be a good choice.

i.g.

```
//route 

[{
  path: '/any-path',
  component: ContainerComponent,
  resolve: {
    store: PathResolver
  }
}]
```

```
//path-resolver.ts
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PathResolver implements Resolve<number> {
    constructor(private store: Store) {
    }

    public resolve(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): Observable<any> {
        this.store.dispatch(LoadMyRoute());

       // You can pass some data to next components as well
        return this.store.pipe(
            select(dataForMyRoute),
            filter(data => !!data), // <- waiting until data is present
            take(1), // <- important to add
        );
    }
}
```

Retrieve data into component

```
constructor(
    protected readonly store: Store,
    protected readonly activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
) {}

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => {
        // everything is here.
    });
}
```

I hope this clarify your questions

Comment: That wasn't exactly what I was looking for but this gives me new perspective, thank you